# how to cache frequently served images?

Tags: caching, grails

I am using an older version of grails. The grails version is 2.2.0. One problem i am seeing with the current application setup is that the log is flooded with get requests for images from the index page. If i click refresh then all the images are re-requested. The log record for images look as follows

```
27.34.20.149 - - [03/Jul/2017:22:50:20 -0600] "GET /uploads/logos/thumbnails/f6dfNSxvksQkrB83_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1599
27.34.20.149 - - [03/Jul/2017:22:50:20 -0600] "GET /uploads/logos/thumbnails/I7w4dlwL1ejngl24_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1599
27.34.20.149 - - [03/Jul/2017:22:50:20 -0600] "GET /uploads/logos/thumbnails/eZhBkSt2BQK9fHES_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1599
27.34.20.149 - - [03/Jul/2017:22:50:20 -0600] "GET /uploads/logos/thumbnails/Wa7tHggCCmf95GH7_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1599
27.34.20.149 - - [03/Jul/2017:22:50:20 -0600] "GET /uploads/logos/thumbnails/3rCuZaRedGvhJGx9_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1599
27.34.20.149 - - [03/Jul/2017:22:50:20 -0600] "GET /uploads/logos/thumbnails/23i2HLxd1XbA0Bvd_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1599
27.34.20.149 - - [03/Jul/2017:22:50:20 -0600] "GET /uploads/logos/thumbnails/lbsBuqo1Imny2Ggl_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1599
27.34.20.149 - - [03/Jul/2017:22:50:20 -0600] "GET /uploads/logos/thumbnails/xtTZU9vrIHzct8sN_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1599
27.34.20.149 - - [03/Jul/2017:22:50:20 -0600] "GET /uploads/logos/thumbnails/rbUZx7D59tP67pfs_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1599
27.34.20.149 - - [03/Jul/2017:22:50:20 -0600] "GET /uploads/logos/thumbnails/7s47yiB3BmAnzMNX_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1599
27.34.20.149 - - [03/Jul/2017:22:50:20 -0600] "GET /uploads/logos/thumbnails/4TvirWFiuhdpWz7I_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1599
27.34.20.149 - - [03/Jul/2017:22:50:20 -0600] "GET /uploads/logos/thumbnails/oSBR4E5jH2m8iFiZ_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1599
27.34.20.149 - - [03/Jul/2017:22:50:21 -0600] "GET /uploads/logos/thumbnails/UGAVMxFQsotu2XNK_thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1599
27.34.20.149 - - [03/Jul/2017:22:50:21 -0600] "GET
```

These are images in the index page of the application and these images are not changed frequently. I am wondering for a manual solution to cache these images so that on every refresh of the page all these images are not re-requested from the application. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: May be of use https://grails.org/plugin/cached-resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cached-resources plugin is great for Grails 2 (credit to Mike W for first mention!).

If you plan to upgrade to 2.4, or 3 at any future point, you're probably better served just taking a look at asset pipeline: http://www.asset-pipeline.com/manual/#grails2 and http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/asset-pipeline but that might be more work for you right now.

However, just as a heads up, note that all of the lines in your log that you included are 404's, and the URL of each is different.  In many environments, an error page won't be cached (it's certainly dependent on your setup, but that's pretty common to avoid false positives) and as long as you're requesting different resources every time (by URL) caching isn't going to help!

Comment: thanks but the links are links to logos in the index page and they are not changed very often. so looks like my best option right now is cached-resources plugin then? i am going to upgrade the app soon to 3 so do you recommend first upgrading rather than including this plugin right now? Thanks!

Comment: cached-resources will definitely be easier for you, if you're on grails 2 for now.  If you're sure those links are working, then that should work for you, but the log file you uploaded shows a lot of HTTP 404 response codes.  I'd try one of those links manually in a browser just to make sure you don't have excess requests being generated.  You can also use the browser's network console (FF or Chrome anyway, not sure about IE) to view all requests and their responses.  I'd hate for you to go to the trouble of putting in cached resources and then find out that wasn't the problem!

Comment: OK, I clearly read your comment wrong.  You say you ARE upgrading to grails 3 soon.  Yes, I'd upgrade first.  That is a pretty involved upgrade, and will require a lot of changes anyway that would probably work around this issue in the first place.